# Get Unique column value along with other. Columns when using inner join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have following query and I need unique value for column

```
Select unique(t.id), log.* 
from tableA log 
inner join tableT t on t.id1=log.id1 
where log.time>=(somedate) 
and log.time<(somedate) 
and ref-id=20 
and ref-id=30 
and t.id not in (select unique t.id 
                 from   tableA log 
                 inner join tableT t on t.id1=log.id1 
                 where log.time>=(somedate) 
                 and log.time<(somedate) 
                 and ref-id=20 
                 and ref-id=30);
```

I am not getting unique values for t.id.Can anyone please help ? I am using oracle data base

Comment: `ref - id`? Looks like odd math.

Comment: As well as join condition.

Comment: It is ref_id.Its a column

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  And what table is `ref_id` in ?  Qualify *all* column references.

Comment: @satya don't comment your mis-types, edit (i.e. fix) them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove LOG.* from the SELECT; UNIQUE (as well as DISTINCT) is applied to all columns you select, not only to the one you put into brackets.

**[EDIT]**

Scott's EMP table contains employees that work in different departments. List of distinct departments is:

```
SQL> select distinct deptno from emp;

    DEPTNO
----------
        30
        20
        10

SQL>
```

If you include additional columns, such as JOB, the list is changed to

```
SQL> select distinct deptno, job from emp order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK
        10 MANAGER
        10 PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST
        20 CLERK
        20 MANAGER
        30 CLERK
        30 MANAGER
        30 SALESMAN

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It is now distinct per DEPTNO **and** per JOB; you can't get only distinct DEPTNO in such a query.

**[EDIT #2: aggregation]**

If "distinct" means *distinct DEPTNO and the first job for that DEPTNO*, then you might need this:

```
SQL> select deptno, min(job) first_job from emp
  2  group by deptno
  3  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO FIRST_JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK
        20 ANALYST
        30 CLERK

SQL>
```

**[EDIT #3, example based on your query]**

```
Select t.id, 
       min(log.id) log_id, 
       min(log.time) log_time,
       <the rest of LOG table columns goes here, all of them with MIN>
from tableA log 
inner join table ...
<the rest of your query goes here>
group by t.id;
```

Comment: I need al the columns from log table as well with unique values from t.id column

Comment: I edited my message, adding an example which shows *why* you can't get what you want. If I misunderstood the question, please, explain what you'd want to get as a result (based on Scott's EMP table; or, if you want to have your data, provide test case - CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, along with the desired result).

Comment: So If we cant get unique dept no then Is there anyother way?

Comment: As I said: please, edit your question and **show us** the desired output. I can't imagine what you are saying.

Comment: As per dept and job table I need like this

Comment: 10 clerk   20 analyst 30 clerk

Comment: That looks like *the first job per department*; what about other jobs?

Comment: Other jobs can be ignored..first job per department is good enough

Comment: OK; I edited my answer, have a look - you'd use aggregation. It means that you should use the same principle in your query - apply MIN function to *all* LOG table's columns, one by one, as you can't use `MIN(log.*)`.

Comment: I tried for single column from log table and error message is not a single group function

Comment: You have to include ALL columns that aren't aggregated into the GROUP BY clause. In your query, that would be the `t.id`.

Comment: I did not get you..Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: Great! Its working.Thank you so much for your help and patience.I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you got the result you needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
Select t.id, log.* 
from tableA log inner join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id1 order by id) as seqnum
      from tableT t
     ) t
     on t.id1 = log.id1 
where log.time >= (somedate) and
      log.time < (somedate) and
      t.seqnum = 1
      ref_id = 20 and ref_id = 30 -- this is ALWAYS false, but I'm ignoring that
```

Notes:

- I have no idea what the subquery is supposed to be doing.
- The conditions on `ref_id` will always evaluate to FALSE, so that logic is almost certainly not what you intend.
- If `ref_id` is in the transaction table, then the conditions should be moved to the subquery.

Comment: Sorry about that.some part of query is missed.My bad